# How to decode WooCommerce Webhook Secret?

Tags: php, woocommerce, webhooks

I can't find any information on what algorithm to use to decode WooCommerce webhook field X-Wc-Webhook-Signature in PHP. Does anyone know how to decode it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question.

For now: can you add some code you already tried? Were happy to help you debugging, but if youre in search of someone to write your code this not the right place.

Comment: Hi Fabian. Sorry for the late reply. I'm not looking for someone to write the code. I am just searching for how WooCommerce is hashing the secret so that I can find the correct algorithm to match the hash on my server. I have not written any code yet, as I do not know what algorithm they use. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on the current answers, this is the PHP code snippet you need:

```
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $request_body, $secret, true));
```

Where $secret is your secret, $request_body is the request body, which can be fetched with `file_get_contents('php://input');`
The $sig value should then be equal to the X-Wc-Webhook-Signature request header.

Comment: I am trying your code but for some reason I can never get the values to match? Could I be missing anything else?

Answer (score 8):

To expand on the laravel solution this is how I created middleware to validate the incoming webhook.

Create middleware. The application that I am using keeps the WooCommerce consumer key and secret in a table assigned to a given store.

```
class ValidateWebhook
{
    /**
     * Validate that the incoming request has been signed by the correct consumer key for the supplied store id
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $signature = $request->header('X-WC-Webhook-Signature');
        if (empty($signature)) {
            return response(['Invalid key'], 401);
        }

        $store_id = $request['store'];
        $consumer_key = ConsumerKeys::fetchConsumerSecretByStoreId($store_id);

        $payload = $request->getContent();
        $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $consumer_key, true));

        if ($signature != $calculated_hmac) {
            return response(['Invalid key'], 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register the middleware in Kernel.php

```
        'webhook' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateWebhook::class,
```

Protect the webhook route with the middleware

```
Route::post('webhook', 'PrintController@webhook')->middleware('webhook');
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution for this question. You need to generate a sha256 hash for the content that was sent [payload] and encode it in base64. Then just compare the generated hash with the received one.

```
$secret = 'your-secret-here';
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$receivedHeaders = apache_request_headers();
$receivedHash = $receivedHeaders['X-WC-Webhook-Signature'];
$generatedHash = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, true));
if($receivedHash === $generatedHash):
        //Verified, continue your code
else:
        //exit
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:
"A base64 encoded HMAC-SHA256 hash of the payload"

I'm guessing that the payload in this instances is the secret you've supplied in the webhook properties.

Source: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#webhooks-properties

**EDIT**

Further digging indicates that the payload is the body of the request.
So you'd use a HMAC library to create a sha256 hash of the payload using your webhook secret, and then base64 encode the result, and do the comparison with `X-Wc-Webhook-Signature` and see if they match.

You can generate a key pair from the following URL:

```
/wc-auth/v1/authorize?app_name=my_app&scope=read_write&user_id=<a_unique_id_that_survives_the_roundtrip>&return_url=<where_to_go_when_the_flow_completes>&callback_url=<your_server_url_that_will_receieve_the_following_params>
```

These are the params the callback URL receieves in the request body:

```
{
  consumer_key: string,
  consumer_secret: string,
  key_permissions: string,
  user_id: string,
}
```

Comment: How do you generate the secret? Is the only way to create one through the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my laravel / lumen function to verify the webhook request, hope it helps someone!

```
private function verifyWebhook(Request $request) {
    $signature = $request->header('x-wc-webhook-signature');

    $payload = $request->getContent();
    $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, 'WOOCOMMERCE_KEY', true));

    if($signature != $calculated_hmac) {
      abort(403);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the answers will fail: Your secret (defined in woocommerce) should only contain letters and numbers!